# Power BI calculate DAX measure cumulatively

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I can't configure how to calculate DAX measure cumulatively. The DAX measure by it self looks like this:

UpdateTicket_ = CALCULATE(Logging[LogDistcount_], Logging[Step] = 7) # DAX measure to filter distinct ID by some condition.

LogDistcount_ = DISTINCTCOUNT(Logging[TicketId]) # DAX measure to calculate distinct ID presented in the featured dataset.

**The ploblem** is that formula construction to calculate cumulatively doesn't allow to sum DAX measure. I mean this: =CALCULATE(SUM(UpdateTicket_)... The formula doesn't give an option to select UpdateTicket_ to make a SUM of it. This measure doesn't appear in the selection list of the SUM formula at all.

**Currently output of the UpdateTicket_ measure looks like this:**

| StartTime_DateOnly | UpdateTicket_ |
| --- | --- |
| 08.11.2022 | 950 |
| 09.11.2022 | 1056 |
| 10.11.2022 | 1056 |
| 11.11.2022 | 1056 |
| 12.11.2022 | 1056 |
| 13.11.2022 | 1056 |

**What I am looking for:**

| StartTime_DateOnly | UpdateTicket_ | UpdateTicket_Cumulatively |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08.11.2022 | 950 | 950 |
| 09.11.2022 | 1056 | 2006 |
| 10.11.2022 | 1056 | 3062 |
| 11.11.2022 | 1056 | 4118 |
| 12.11.2022 | 1056 | 5174 |
| 13.11.2022 | 1056 | 6230 |

Comment: BTW, that measure does not appear as a target for a SUM function because only columns are summable. Measures are inherently scalar. To sum a measure, you would need to give it some row context - i.e. a table-iterator (SUMX?) or a calculated column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you can accept the following solution:

Let Power BI create the measure for you by going to *Quick measure* - *Running total*

[image]

You'll get the following expression:

```
UpdateTicket_Cumulatively = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[UpdateTicket_]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Table'[StartTime_DateOnly]),
        ISONORAFTER('Table'[StartTime_DateOnly], MAX('Table'[StartTime_DateOnly]), DESC)
    )
```

and a table like this:

[image]

Note that this works with both measures and columns.

Comment: If UpdateTicket_ is a measure itself the 3rd line of the above expression will be simply `[UpdateTicket_],`